# Removing 'Recent name' from Stack Exchange profile

Tags: support, profile-page, recent-names

I've searched around Meta (I may be looking at the wrong place) and haven't found a question regarding this issue.

I would like to remove "Recent names" or better, any particular name inside that field from my Stack Exchange profile: how could I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot.

The information is not public in any case, it is only visible to you and moderators. The information is not going to be hidden from moderators as it is needed for them to be able to moderate the site effectively. The list is also limited to name changes in the last 90 days.

The general public cannot see the list.

Also see [Who can see the "past names" field in user profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116793/who-can-see-the-past-names-field-in-user-profiles) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> your guess is correct: only moderators & devs can view this info.

Comment: Oh alright, I do not in any way mean to sound rude but is there any way I could verify this?

Comment: @Juxhin: see a moderator's answer on a [related feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166925/consider-not-include-default-user-name-in-the-list-of-recent-names-if-it-wa): *As you've stated, normal users cannot even see it - only you and moderators.*

Comment: @Juxhin You could simply go to your profile in a browser that's logged out and see if it's there or not.

Comment: @Juxhin: it is also quite easily verified by *logging out* or using the private / incognito browsing feature of your browser to look at your profile.

Comment: @juxhin, consider this extra verification: No one but mods and  employees with mod access can see that.