# Is there a way to see your previously used names on your profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, recent-names

I can't seem to find a way to look up the previous names of a profile. I think it was called `Recent Names`.

I'm pretty sure that **was** a feature a while ago... but it might have been removed when the new profile came out? Of course, maybe I just don't see it anywhere.

I also haven't found any questions about it.

Comment: Hmm. There's a link that mods get, but I can't find it on my own profile on other sites, so it looks like it's not available. I can't see why it shouldn't be though.

Comment: @ChrisF it's strange because it used to be there, available only to you and the mods. It says so [right here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269019/2413303).